# And another one type error

Tags: haskell

```
sumOfSquare :: Int -> Int -> Int
sumOfSquare a b = a * a + b * b

hipotenuse :: Int -> Int -> Int
hipotenuse a b = truncate(sqrt(x))
           where x = fromIntegral(sumOfSquare a b)

squareCheck :: Int -> Bool
squareCheck n = truncate(sqrt(x)) * truncate(sqrt(x)) == n
         where x = fromIntegral n

isItSquare :: Int -> Int -> Bool
isItSquare a b = squareCheck (sumOfSquare a b)

calc :: (Integral a) => a -> [(a, a, a)]
calc a = [(x, y, (hipotenuse x y)) | x <- [1..a], y <-[1..a], (isItSquare x y)]
```

Error message:

```
Prelude> :load "some.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( some.hs, interpreted )

some.hs:16:74:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' against inferred type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `calc' at some.hs:15:18
    In the first argument of `isItSquare', namely `x'
    In the expression: (isItSquare x y)
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: (isItSquare x y)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

As I understand the type of 'x' and 'y'. Is it right? Is it square require the Int. But what is the type 'x' and 'y'?  I thinked they are Int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your type is too general.  You are passing `x` and `y` to `isItSquare`, which is expecing `Int`s, but you don't know that `x` and `y` are `Int`s.  They could be, but they could be any other instance of `Integral` as well.  Either change the signature to the more specific:

```
calc :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
```

Or have your helper functions work on more general types:

```
squareCheck :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You've declared `sumOfSquare`, `hipotenuse`, `squareCheck` and `isItSquare` as operating on `Int`.

However, you've said that `calc` can use any type `a`, as long as `a` is `Integral`.

Either declare `calc` like this:

```
calc :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
```

...or change all your other functions like this:

```
sumOfSquare :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
calc :: (Integral a) => a -> [(a, a, a)]
calc a = [(x, y, (hipotenuse x y)) | x <- [1..a], y <-[1..a], (isItSquare x y)]
```

`a` has type `a` (the signature explicitly says so, that's what "is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for `calc`" means), and `x` is taken from the list `[1..a]`, so it also has type `a` (and same for `y`).